# How to add a new listener on a new port and restrict it to one instance only

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, security, oracle-11g, listener

I am running oracle 11.2.3 and we have a server with multiple instances running. All of them are registered to port 1521 with the default listener. Now we are required to make one instance available on a new port. I was wondering if there is a way to add a new listener to a new port and restrict it to register only one instance so that this listener can not make connections for other instances.

Current Listener Configuration:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    )
  )
```

Comment: We have our qa database instance on the same server as the prod one for some unrelated reasons. We want to create a firewall flow from qa webserver to this server to connect to qa database. This will create a security concern since prod database will also be accessible so we want to keep qa and prod database listener on separate ports and open the firewall flow only to the qa listener.

Comment: We have same home for all instances

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation about configuring multiple listeners in listener.ora, and about static service registration for each. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netag/configuring-and-administering-oracle-net-listener.html#GUID-C3C40DBA-4282-41E1-9562-4B8B10947C4E

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

QA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1526))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=prod.us.example.com)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/oracle12c)
      (SID_NAME=prod))
  )

SID_LIST_QA=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=qa.us.example.com)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/oracle12c)
      (SID_NAME=qa))
  )
```

If you are working with Oracle Enterprise Edition, then another option would be to use Oracle Connection Manager; it would allow you to restrict client access by IP address and database service name. I wrote a white paper on it several years ago, but the basics are still the same with the latest versions: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/deploying-an-oracle-11gr2-connection-manager/

Comment: You'd probably also want to set `DYNAMIC_REGISTRATION_<listener> = off` so the listener stays dedicated to the instance(s) in its `SID_LIST`.